# Jest Memory Leak when running test cases on redux connected components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, heap-memory, redux-saga

When I run my jest tests, I got the following error , this particularly happens with the redux connected components and forwardRef:true is one parameters of the connect wrapper component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OqkI.png)

How can I fix my jest configuration to prevent this?

Comment: This solve my issue, take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68307839/9331978

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do some cleanup in the after hook for each test.  You might also consider whether its appropriate to provide a mock for the redux store, so that you are isolating the component tests from the reducer tests.

Comment: I am doing the clean up in aftereach lifecycle method which will run after each test case ,still getting the same issue.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9980

Comment: https://making.close.com/posts/finding-the-cause-of-a-memory-leak-in-jest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600493/high-jest-heap-memory-usage-in-javascript-react-projects

Comment: https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html